# C# - e.KeyChar != '.' not working

Tags: c#, events

In my Windows Forms application I have a TextBox and applied to it the KeyPress event to accept just numbers. In the moment, my script is this way:

```
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
        && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) 
        && e.KeyChar != '.')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

The problem is that in `e.KeyChar != '.'` it doesn't work, my TextBox is accepting numbers and dots. I don't understand why because I say to the script that if the pressed key be different of dot (.), then doesn't input it. Some examples of values I'm receiveing are:

- **x8361** - Doesn't accept
- **56491** - Accept
- **15466.5** - Accept : This is the failure. It might not accept but `!=` doesn't do anything there.

Comment: Did you mean `||` (or)? Now it should be no digit, AND no '.' to be handled. Take care of precedence though.

Comment: @Caramiriel. No, it really is &&.

Comment: You have another problem, someone can paste a string into your textbox and it would bypass your validation.

Comment: change != to == like i wrote and it will work.

Comment: Also 1.1.1.1.1.1. is valid. You'd be much better off accepting everything and validating on something like text changed, returning to the previous correct or default value

Comment: @James Not `Changed`, [`Validating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating(v=vs.110).aspx). That’s what the event is for. Everything else (especially OP’s approach) is bad UX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even better solution. With this one you can only use: 0123456789 and backspace

```
        if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != '\b')
            e.Handled = true
```

Comment: No. If I have a dot (.), I don't want to set e.Handled to true, just if doesn't contain.

Comment: So you want to be able to put in a dot (.) ?

Comment: No, I want not be able to put a dot. With your code, My TextBox accepts all. I want to accept just [1~9] chars. ONLY them. I need int, not a float/double.

Comment: the problem may be in C# compiler...
Because I do for tests:

if (e.KeyChar == '.') MessageBox.Show("dot");
/* If I input a dot, it messages me */

if (e.KeyChar != '.') MessageBox.Show("Not a dot");
/ * If I don't put a dot, it doesn't message me */

Comment: And your code accepts all, also dots and other symbols

Comment: look at my last part.

Comment: @Marcelo This makes for a terrible user interface. **Do not do this**. What if the user wants to paste some (wrongly formatted) text from another source? This approach will either accept invalid input if the user pastes it, or it will reject every pasted input from the user. Both are terrible and will piss the user off. The correct way is to validate input in the [`Validating` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @KonradRudolph I could attribute other events to the same static method. And the application is also for a DataCollector without the copy/paste option. :)

Comment: @Marcelo “And the application is also for a DataCollector without the copy/paste option” – then make a **separate** validation routine for that one.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I am missing something, wouldn't it make more sense to check for what *is* acceptable rather than what isn't?

```
e.Handled = !(char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) || char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == '.');
```

This is by no means a complete solution however because this would still allow values like `12345.67.89.` which obviously aren't numerically formatted correctly.

A more robust solution would be to use a [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or allow freetext but validate the *entire* input rather then each individual `char`.

Comment: This wont handle if you press shift key and another key.

Comment: You are missing something.  It swallows digits and doesn't permit backspacing.

Comment: @HansPassant fair point, however, I haven't used WinForms in a while I assumed that `Handled` meant allow... updated.